# Must the update form in Django update all fields of an object?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have created multiple update forms in my Django app.

My question is: does Django need to update every single field of an object, or is there a way to only update fields that were actually changed?

So, for example, I might have a form with `Airport Name`, `Airport City`, `Airport Country`. And I might use the update form to update the `Country`. Does Django also need the `Name` and `City` form fields filled and then update, or is there a way to leave them blank and not update the database?

**EDIT**

This is the model:

```
class Airport(models.Model):
    airport_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Aeroporto")
    airport_city = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Cidade")
    airport_country = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="País")
```

And the form:

```
class UpdateAirport(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateAirport, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['airport_name'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['airport_city'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['airport_country'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})


    class Meta:
        model = Airport
        fields = ('airport_name', 'airport_city', 'airport_country' )
```

And my view:

```
@login_required(login_url='../accounts/login/')
def airport_upd(request, id):
    ts = Airport.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateAirport(request.POST, instance=ts)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('flights')
    else:
        form = UpdateAirport(initial={'airport_name': ts.airport_name, 'airport_city': ts.airport_city, 'airport_country': ts.airport_country})
    return render(request, 'backend/aiport_update.html', {'form': form, 'ts': ts})
```

And I am using Postgresql.

Comment: Your question is too broad, answers may differ between database engines, model definition, form validation etc.

Comment: I'll add my forms and models code.

Comment: @Sayse you can see now more details.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new row in `Airport` table, fields cannot be null or blank because are required, but when you update that row you don`t need to fill all fields if they already have a value

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own form validation by overriding the existing one

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    clean = form.cleaned_data
    airport_name = clean.get('airport_name')
    airport_city = clean.get('airport_city')
    if airport_name:
        form.instance.airport_name = airport_name
    if airport_city:
        form.instance.airport_city = airport_city

    return super(UpdateAirport, self).form_valid(form)
```

Make sure that those fields are not required

Answer (score 0):

With an `UpdateView` subclass, one would replace the `form_valid` method.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save( commit = False)
    self.object.save( update_fields=['name', ... ])  # save only the specified fields
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Invaluable reference: [Classy CBVs](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/)